# how to get my data shown in my dynamic URL with PHP

Tags: php, heidisql

How should my test.php get data from a database? My database name is "example" and the things i want to get are test1, test2, test3.

```html
<html>
<a  href="test.php?ID=<?php echo $kerko_rezultatin['id_object'];?>">
</a> 
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a connection to you database:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", 
"db_name");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Then you need to create a query to select data from your database:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
  while($kerko_rezultatin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<a  href='test.php?ID=".$kerko_rezultatin['id_object']."'> </a>"  
;}
```

Comment: I already have this one , but the question is  what should I write in test.php, this code that u have wrote is in my index.php.
Simplier , when I click the id--> to get only information of that ID . do you get it ?

Comment: btw qenke shqiptare , shpresoj qe mkuptove

Comment: Nope ste kuptova

Comment: ket qe e ke shkru ti e kam paraqit ne index.php, dmth i got the id from database, kur e klikoj linkun e mar rezultatin "test.php?ID=1" por un dua te marr me shum te dhena prej databazes dhe posaqerisht prej qasaj Id, dhe te me paraqiten ne test.php

Comment: $get_id = $_GET['ID']; //to get the value of id from your url
SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE ID=$get_id //use this query to get the other data from your table